# Instagram python bot, How to make it close and restart when i run on a error?

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, instagram, bots

So i got this Bot for  Instagram on GitHub .
I have edited the script so it run the longest time possible i guess ,until I have 3 ,"error 400" in a row then the script stop to prevent get banned.

I want to make a loop that, when I encountered an error, it closes and restart again.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import time

sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'src'))

from check_status import check_status
from feed_scanner import feed_scanner
from follow_protocol import follow_protocol
from instabot import InstaBot
from unfollow_protocol import unfollow_protocol

bot = InstaBot(
login="USERNAME",
password="PASSWORD",
like_per_day=2500,
comments_per_day=1500,
tag_list=['photo', '', 'car', 'nature', 'city'],
tag_blacklist=['racist', 'example', 'example', 'example', ],
user_blacklist={},
max_like_for_one_tag=50,
follow_per_day=0,
follow_time=1 * 60,
unfollow_per_day=300,
unfollow_break_min=15,
unfollow_break_max=30,
log_mod=0,
proxy='',
# List of list of words, each of which will be used to generate comment
# For example: "This shot feels wow!"
comment_list=[["this", "the", "your"],
              ["photo", "picture", "pic", "shot", "snapshot"],
              ["is", "looks", "is really"],
              ["great", "super", "good", "very good", "good", "wow",
               "WOW", "cool", "GREAT","magnificent", "magical",
               "very cool", "stylish", "beautiful", "so beautiful",
               "so stylish", "so professional", "lovely",
               "so lovely", "glorious","so glorious",
               "very glorious", "adorable", "excellent", "amazing"],
              [".", "..", "...", "!", "!!", "!!!"]],
# Use unwanted_username_list to block usernames containing a string
## Will do partial matches; i.e. 'mozart' will block 'legend_mozart'
### 'free_followers' will be blocked because it contains 'free'
unwanted_username_list=[
    'second', 'stuff', 'art', 'project', 'love', 'life', 'food', 'blog',
    'free', 'keren', 'photo', 'graphy', 'indo', 'travel', 'art', 'shop',
    'store', 'sex', 'toko', 'jual', 'online', 'murah', 'jam', 'kaos',
    'case', 'baju', 'fashion', 'corp', 'tas', 'butik', 'grosir', 'karpet',
    'sosis', 'salon', 'skin', 'care', 'cloth', 'tech', 'rental', 'kamera',
    'beauty', 'express', 'kredit', 'collection', 'impor', 'preloved',
    'follow', 'follower', 'gain', '.id', '_id', 'bags'
    ],
    unfollow_whitelist=['example_user_1', 'example_user_2'])
    while True:

    #print("# MODE 0 = ORIGINAL MODE BY LEVPASHA")
    #print("## MODE 1 = MODIFIED MODE BY KEMONG")
    #print("### MODE 2 = ORIGINAL MODE + UNFOLLOW WHO DON'T FOLLOW BACK")
    #print("#### MODE 3 = MODIFIED MODE : UNFOLLOW USERS WHO DON'T FOLLOW          YOU BASED ON RECENT FEED")
#print("##### MODE 4 = MODIFIED MODE : FOLLOW USERS BASED ON RECENT FEED ONLY")
#print("###### MODE 5 = MODIFIED MODE : JUST UNFOLLOW EVERYBODY, EITHER YOUR FOLLOWER OR NOT")

################################
##  WARNING   ###
################################

# DON'T USE MODE 5 FOR A LONG PERIOD. YOU RISK YOUR ACCOUNT FROM GETTING BANNED
## USE MODE 5 IN BURST MODE, USE IT TO UNFOLLOW PEOPLE AS MANY AS YOU WANT IN SHORT TIME PERIOD

    mode = 0

    #print("You choose mode : %i" %(mode))
    #print("CTRL + C to cancel this operation or wait 30 seconds to   start")
#time.sleep(30)

if mode == 0:
    bot.new_auto_mod()

elif mode == 1:
    check_status(bot)
    while bot.self_following - bot.self_follower > 200:
        unfollow_protocol(bot)
        time.sleep(10 * 60)
        check_status(bot)
    while bot.self_following - bot.self_follower < 400:
        while len(bot.user_info_list) < 50:
            feed_scanner(bot)
            time.sleep(5 * 60)
            follow_protocol(bot)
            time.sleep(10 * 60)
            check_status(bot)

elif mode == 2:
    bot.bot_mode = 1
    bot.new_auto_mod()

elif mode == 3:
    unfollow_protocol(bot)
    time.sleep(10 * 60)

elif mode == 4:
    feed_scanner(bot)
    time.sleep(60)
    follow_protocol(bot)
    time.sleep(10 * 60)

elif mode == 5:
    bot.bot_mode = 2
    unfollow_protocol(bot)

else:
    print("Wrong mode!")
```

- NOTE :
  Editted some of the description to make it a little more readable and specific of what he/she is asking
  *

Comment: could you please leave a link on the github page and also get the error of the application, if not we cannot really do much.

Comment: your rigth , https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py

Comment: and for the error its ""error 400"" for too much coments

Comment: define a function which starts this script, catch the error, when error cought rerun script

Comment: @d3fco since you encountered so many errors, I assume you didn't get all the requirements for this script to work or setting it up incorrectly.

Comment: yes i do .
the bot was ready to use after some modifications, like user name and password 
i can execute 120 ,to 160 like and coments before have the errors and the errors are always after a random number of like or coments execute . 
but the real question was no the errors but how coul i make it restart afrer whitout another bot just whit some extra code

Comment: thankyou @anuj i will try

Answer (score 1):

Do error handling and put it in a while loop, and add some sleep to prevent suspension.

```
#here is an expamle of the code
while True:
   try:
     your codes here
   expect:
     code to show that error has occured
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised I encounter so many errors because I did not had  the requirement  `pyLint` on my computer

Answer (score 0):

If try to loop the entire process there is a chance of login error, because ad per instagram polices, you will not be able to login to instagram more than 5 time in a time period with same ip address. So you should only loop through the other process other than login

**Code Here**

```py
from instabot import InstaBot
bot = InstaBot(login="USERNAME",password="PASSWORD")

while:
   try:
     //Your code here
   expect:
    //What to do if error occured
```